# UFT Doesn't recognise an Object that Object Spy can see

Tags: hp-uft

Object spy is able to highlight the element in the application, and the front end of my test is in the correct place, however, each time it reaches this point it fails to find the Link("Contacts").

If Browser("SugarCRM").Page("SugarCRM").Link("Contacts").Exist Then
    Browser("SugarCRM").Page("SugarCRM").Link("Contacts").Click
End If

This is the Dynamic wait approach I've tried to use, and each time it moves on. The object was captured by recording, and then reinforced with an accurate relative Xpath (This was my first attempt at a fix). Is there any reason that my dynamic wait, and accurate location would fail?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it highlight the given object at runtime ? and you would like to click it,  correct ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to have been a browser/page conflict issue with IE 11. I fired up and configured Chrome and it works smooth and stable.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can change this :Link("Contacts").Exist to Link("Contacts").Exist(5)...ie it will check for 5 seconds wether the object exists or not....see if this works.
You could simply right :
Browser("SugarCRM").Page("SugarCRM").Link("Contacts").click, and see what error it throws. With this error you can solve ur problem
Can you highlight the object from object repository ? and is the smart identification off ? Make sure smart identification is off......try this stuff..see if it helps